# Add New Product Image Type (Attribute) in Magento

Tags: php, image, magento, attributes, product

I am trying to add a new image type in the product admin panel. I created a new attribute (hero_banner) set it's type to media image (similar to how the thumbnail image and small_image have been set up). I then added it to the Default attribute set under images. It appears fine in the admin panel and allows you to assign images as the hero but then when I try and echo the image path into the phtml the templates stop rendering. The code I am using to echo the image is below:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hero_banner'); ?>
```

This is being done within a product foreach iteration so I have the $_product variable and I am able to echo other images fine (such as thumbnail, small_image etc). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dino,How you did that, I also wan to implement same.Could you please share some information with me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to select this attribute too in your collection like this before the collection is actually loaded:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('hero_banner');
```

It works fine on my code, but I dont know if you already have rewrited the block where your collection is defined (it won't work in your template since the collection is already loaded there)
Maybe you can configure your hero_attribute to add this addAttributeToSelect directly in Magento back office, I'll have a look

Edit: Ok, I think I've got it, you won't have to worry about collection & rewrites :) 
If you use this attribute on product listing, you have to set the property "visible on product listing" to true to your image attribute (in the admin panel attribute management)

Good luck

Comment: Absolute legend thank you worked like a charm. Although I am using custom code to retrieve my product collection I am using code taken from List.php to try and conform to the Magento best practices. The code which adds the attributes is: ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) which I would like to pull in the hero. Any idea where I can edit this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? You should have this attribute available even outside a List block if you use the getProductAttribute() (have a look in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Config::getProductAttribute())

Comment: What I am saying is in that method call I posted the attributes for other images (e.g. small_image, thumbnail etc) are included. It would be nice if I could find out how where they include them so that I don't have to say include the hero attribute everywhere I want to use it. I'm not massively bothered but it's just a nicer way of doing it.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you can set "visible on product listing" to false, and add ->addAttributeToSelect('hero_banner') where you call ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()).

Comment: That is what I am doing and it's what I want to avoid doing. This method call Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes() is obviously returning an array of attributes it selects. What I am saying is it would be better if I could add my attribute to whereever this array of attributes is coming from.

Comment: well, I think you can't since the getProductAttribute only retrieve attributes available for the product view list... Have a look in the source code of the method, you'll see what I mean ;)

Comment: This worked for me. However, there's a strange bug (version 1.6.1.0): When creating the custom attribute in the backend, you have to set the product to be "Visible in the product frontend" BEFORE you switch the attribute's type to "Image". Otherwise, the option to set the visibility will be hidden.